# List physical drive space

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

I have around 200 servers and I need to get the disk space & logical drive space details (free space, used space & total space).

Here is my PowerShell query.

```
$infoObjects = New-Object PSObject
foreach ($machine in $servers) {
  $counts = Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive" -ComputerName $machine
  $total_disk =  @($counts).Count
  $i = 0
  $total_disk = $total_disk -1

  for (; $i -le $total_disk; $i++) {
    $a = $i
    $a  = Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive WHERE DeviceID='\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE$i'" -ComputerName $machine

    $b = $i
    $b = [math]::round($a.size /1GB)

    Add-Member -InputObject $infoObject -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Physical_Disk $i" -Value $b
  }
  $infoObject | Export-Csv -Path Inventory.csv -Append -Force -NoTypeInformation 
}
```

It is giving me desired output but if some of serverd have more than one disk or have more logical drive than the output is stuck with that number of drives of first server.  It is not giving me output in the CSV file of rest of the drives of other servers.

Here is the example about what I am saying.

```
ServerName Physical_Disk 0 Physical_Disk 1 Physical_Disk 2 Physical_Disk 3
Server1 100 20  40
Server2 85
Server3 60  450 200 420
Server4 60
Server5 60                  
Server10    55  20  40
```

If it seems like I am not able to explain the problem. Let me try again.

- First server has 2 physical drives that are coming in my output file (CSV).
- Second server also has 2 physical drives that are also in CSV file.
- But third server has more than 2 drives and only 2 drives are showing in output.

Comment: You are limited because the first server only has the two disks. You need to make empty properties for the maximum amout of disks if you want them to be grouped this way. This is the way PowerShell is grouping the data together in order to be displayed. The first server doesnt have those extra disks. You could artificially create disk values for X drives where X is something like 10. Most servers dont have 10 disks.

Comment: Your sample data does not contain all the details that you  are asking for in your first sentence

Comment: For the sake of your future self's sanity, please use meaningful variable names. They don't cost extra.

Comment: Why not just remove your first code block in place of the new one.

Comment: @Matt Hi Matt, could you explain more? or any example/sample.

Comment: @404 What he means is that the second code block in your script is a more complete version of the first one, so you should simply have replaced the first one with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to point that there is several places where error *could* occur. The purpose of this answer is to address the unknown number of headers. I would recommend that you run this in place to see what it is trying to show you before you attempt to integrate this.

```
# Gather all wmi drives query at once
$alldisksInfo = Get-WmiObject –query "SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive" -ComputerName $servers -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Group-Object __Server

# Figure out the maximum number of disks
$MaximumDrives = $alldisksInfo | Measure-Object -Property Count -Maximum | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Maximum

# Build the objects, making empty properties for the drives that dont exist for each server where need be. 
$servers | ForEach-Object{
    # Clean the hashtable
    $infoObject = [ordered]@{}

    # Populate Server
    $infoObject.Server = $_    

    # Add other simple properties here
    $infoObject.PhysicalMemory = (Get-WmiObject Win32_PhysicalMemory -ComputerName $infoObject.Server | Measure-Object Capacity -Sum).Sum/1gb

    # Add the disks information from the $diskInfo Array
    $serverDisksWMI = $alldisksInfo | Where-Object{$_.Name -eq $infoObject.Server} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Group

    for($diskIndex =0; $diskIndex -lt $MaximumDrives;$diskIndex++){
        $infoObject."PhysicalDisk$diskIndex" = [Math]::Round(($serverDisksWMI | Where-Object{($_.DeviceID -replace "^\D*") -eq $diskIndex} | Select -Expand Size)/1GB)
    }

    # Create the custom object now.
    New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $infoObject
} # | Export-Csv ....
```

Since this uses the pipeline you can easily add `export-CSV` on the end of this.

Comment: @404 I can only think that you didn't copy the code correctly or made changes. I run this code using an array  of computer names for `$server` and I do not get issues. That is obviously the output from a hashtable but mine does not generate hashtable output as it is converted to a ps object.

Comment: I have raised another question related to this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34674122/powershell-issue-in-export-array-to-csv-file

Answer (score 2):

`Export-Csv` assumes that all objects in your list are uniform, i.e. that they all have the same properties, just with different values. It takes the properties of the first element to determine what to export. Either make sure that all objects have the same properties, or use a different output method, for instance putting all disk information in an array per host and write that to the output file, e.g. like this:

```
foreach ($machine in $servers) {
  $disks = @($machine)
  $disks += Get-WmiObject -Computer $machine -Class Win32_DiskDrive |
            ForEach-Object { [Math]::Round($_.Size/1GB) }
  $disks -join ',' | Add-Content 'C:\path\to\output.csv'
}
```

BTW, you don't need multiple WMI queries, since the first one already returns all disks including their sizes.

Comment: Should `$_.Size/1GB` not be `$_/1GB` since you expanded in the previous select? Or just remove the `select`

Comment: Indeed it should. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If there are other multiple queries then how can i export them in csv file. As i will have to show OS type, RAM size, Domain name as well.

Comment: @404 build an object with those details..... One of them will be what Ansgar has shown you

Comment: @404 Since those probably don't vary in number you could simply append them before appending the disk sizes. If you have other elements than just the disks that can vary in number you probably will have to build objects and make sure that all have the same properties (i.e. add missing properties with empty values).

Comment: Is there any example for the same? $infoObjects = New-Object PSObject
Foreach ($machine in $servers)
{  some WMI query} $infoObject | Export-Csv -path Inventory.csv -Append -Force -NoTypeInformation 
} This is how i am doing at the moment.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers thanks for your answer i ran your query and it is creating the output.csv but i didn't found heading over there. If i want to run this query where do i need to place the same. $processor = Get-WMIObject -Query "Select * from win32_Processor" -ComputerName $machine to get processor count.

Comment: My code doesn't create headers, because it's unknown which fields the file will contain. And please avoid scope creep. Adding the processor count is veering off the topic of this question.

Answer (score 0):

I Have below script:
And I am looking for help to convert the output to *Excel* format

```
$Pather = Get-Content C:\Servers.txt
foreach($Path in $Pather)
{
  (Get-Acl $Path).access | ft $path,IdentityReference,FileSystemRights,AccessControlType,IsInherited -auto
}
```