# Output server information to Excel file

Tags: excel, powershell

I've a PowerShell script that can generate server status info to me. My problem now is I want to output result to an Excel file.

PowerShell code:

```
function getwmiinfo ($svr) {
  gwmi -Query "select * from Win32_ComputerSystem" -ComputerName $svr |
    select Name, Model, Manufacturer, Description, DNSHostName, Domain,
           DomainRole, PartOfDomain, NumberOfProcessors, SystemType,
           TotalPhysicalMemory, UserName, Workgroup |
    Format-Table -Property * -Autosize | Out-String -Width 10000

  gwmi -Query "select * from Win32_OperatingSystem" -ComputerName $svr |
    select Name, Version, FreePhysicalMemory, OSLanguage, OSProductSuite,
           OSType, ServicePackMajorVersion, ServicePackMinorVersion |
    Format-Table -Property * -Autosize | Out-String -Width 10000

  gwmi -Query "select * from Win32_PhysicalMemory" -ComputerName $svr |
    select Name, Capacity, DeviceLocator, Tag |
    Format-Table -Autosize

  gwmi -Query "select * from Win32_LogicalDisk where DriveType=3" -ComputerName $svr |
    select Name, FreeSpace, Size |
    Format-Table -Autosize
}

$servers = Get-Content 'servers.txt'
foreach ($server in $servers) {
  $results = gwmi -query "select StatusCode from Win32_PingStatus where Address = '$server'"
  $responds = $false
  foreach ($result in $results) {
    if ($result.statuscode -eq 0) {
      $responds = $true
      break
    }
  }
  if ($responds) {
    getwmiinfo $server
  } else {
    Write-Output "$server does not respond"
  }
}
```

Output to Excel:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Export-Csv` (`Export-Csv  file path -NoTypeInformation`). This is the command.
If you want to use array then you will have to define that. You can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34633699/list-physical-drive-space).

E.g. `$variable | Export-Csv c:\output.csv -notypeinformtion`