# Issue in export Array to CSV file

Tags: csv, powershell, powershell-2.0

I have list of machine in text file and I am trying to get the details of physical drives, OS architecture and physical memory. With the help of Matt (SO user) here is the powershell script.

```
$server = Get-Content .\Server.txt
#$infoObject11 = @{}
$infoObject11 = @{}
foreach ($server in $servers) {
    # Gather all wmi drives query at once
    $alldisksInfo = Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive" -ComputerName $server -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Group-Object __Server

    # Figure out the maximum number of disks
    $MaximumDrives = $alldisksInfo | Measure-Object -Property Count -Maximum | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Maximum

    # Build the objects, making empty properties for the drives that dont exist for each server where need be. 
    $server | ForEach-Object {
        # Clean the hashtable
        $infoObject1 = @{}
        # Populate Server
        $infoObject1.Server = $server 
        $HOSTNAME = Get-WMIObject -Query "Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem" -ComputerName $infoObject1.Server
        # Add other simple properties here
        $infoObject1.PhysicalMemory = (Get-WmiObject Win32_PhysicalMemory -ComputerName $infoObject1.Server | Measure-Object Capacity -Sum).Sum/1gb
        $infoObject1.OSarchitecture =$HOSTNAME.osarchitecture

        # Add the disks information from the $diskInfo Array
        $serverDisksWMI = $alldisksInfo | Where-Object{$_.Name -eq $infoObject1.Server} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Group

        for ($diskIndex =0; $diskIndex -lt $MaximumDrives;$diskIndex++) {
            $infoObject1."PhysicalDisk$diskIndex" = [Math]::Round(($serverDisksWMI | Where-Object{($_.DeviceID -replace "^\D*") -eq $diskIndex} | Select -Expand Size)/1GB)
        }


    }
    # Create the custom object now.
    New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $infoObject1  | Export-Csv -path .\Server_Inventory_$((Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy')).csv -NoTypeInformation 
}
```

Problem is in the CSV file I am getting single machine details but in `server.txt` file there are more than 1 machine. If I print `$infoObject1` before `New-Object` then I can see there are details of multiple machine. It seems like some issue with array and I am not able to export it in CSV.

Can anybody please suggest on this.

Comment: Everytime the `ForEach-Object` loop runs, you overwrite `$infoObject1` with a new HashTable.

Comment: So, any advise what do i need to do to fix this?

Comment: Use another variable name ? Increment an array ? I think you can fix this by yourself based on @Mathias R. Jessen's comment

Comment: @sodawillow There is a HUGE performance issue that the op created with the code by adding an extra loop as well. Look at how `$alldisksInfo` is calculated in my answer to the question this came from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are having issues integrating my code. You have added a second loop that should not be there. Also as other users pointed out you are not creating the per server object *outside* the loop. [The answer, from where your code comes from, has that part correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34637231/3829407). I had even showed you where to put the `Export-CSV`.

```
$servers = Get-Content .\Server.txt

# Gather all wmi drives query at once
$alldisksInfo = Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive" -ComputerName $servers -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Group-Object __Server

# Figure out the maximum number of disks
$MaximumDrives = $alldisksInfo | Measure-Object -Property Count -Maximum | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Maximum

# Build the objects, making empty properties for the drives that dont exist for each server where need be. 
$servers | ForEach-Object {
    # Clean the hashtable
    $infoObject1 = @{}
    # Populate Server
    $infoObject1.Server = $_ 
    # Add other simple properties here
    $infoObject1.PhysicalMemory = (Get-WmiObject Win32_PhysicalMemory -ComputerName $infoObject1.Server | Measure-Object Capacity -Sum | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Sum)/1GB
    $infoObject1.OSarchitecture = Get-WMIObject -Query "Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem" -ComputerName $infoObject1.Server | Select-Object -ExpandProperty OSArchitecture

    # Add the disks information from the $diskInfo Array
    $serverDisksWMI = $alldisksInfo | Where-Object{$_.Name -eq $infoObject1.Server} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Group

    for ($diskIndex =0; $diskIndex -lt $MaximumDrives;$diskIndex++) {
        $infoObject1."PhysicalDisk$diskIndex" = [Math]::Round(($serverDisksWMI | Where-Object{($_.DeviceID -replace "^\D*") -eq $diskIndex} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Size)/1GB)
    }

    # Create the custom object now for this pass in the loop.
    New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $infoObject1  
} | Export-Csv -path .\Server_Inventory_$((Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy')).csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I had a couple mistakes from your copied code. So if you looked at this code previous to now I would update and try again.

Comment: one question if i have multiple machines in server.txt then does this script will work? Because i am getting multiple errors. Get-WmiObject : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ComputerName'. The argument is null or empty. Supply an argument that is not null or empty and then try the command again.

Comment: When were you testing this code? I had some issues before as I missed updating some of your variables. Let me double check to be sure I got them all. You should just have to test the result of `-ComputerName` to debug this but give me a moment.

Comment: @404 I just checked my _current_ code and it ran fine. Again there we errors about 20 minutes ago that you might have copied. Try again with the _whole code as it is now_.

Comment: powershell version is 2 and now i am getting multiple error. Unable to find type [ordered]: make sure that the assembly containing this type is loaded. Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] doesn't contain a method named 'op_Division'.

Comment: You have PowerShell 2! That changes things. My code works on v3. Give me a bit.

Comment: @404 Have a look at it again now. The one issue you will have is column order now.

Comment: now i am getting error - Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] doesn't contain a method named 'op_Division'.

Comment: @404 I missed something about 3.0 then. Can you tell me _where_ though to save me the hassle. I need to know which line is the issue.

Comment: I had missed removing a bracket. I just tested my current code on v2 and it works. In the future you should add your version into the question.

Comment: sure i will do that in future. Let me try again. I just checked and error is on line 23 char 179.

Comment: I wonder if it has to do with the data that your servers are returning. I was testing with server with 3 disks. My logic is possibly breaking and returning unexpected results with larger disk counts. Do you have a server with more than 10 disks?

Comment: You should reduce your sample server to a smaller number. I think the return data for at least one server is not something I was able to test with and I would like to see the WMI disk data for that box.

Comment: I am running it on local machine and machines have 2 disk at the moment but in case of server, some of them have more than 8 disks

Comment: The logic I was using was based on teh DeviceID looking like this: `\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0` if they are different on other servers/hardware then odd things could happen. Checking win32_diskdrive on those systems will give you an idea.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach ($server in $servers) {
   ...
   New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $infoObject1 |
     Export-Csv -Path .\Server_Inventory_$((Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy')).csv -NoTypeInformation 
}
```

You're exporting *inside* the loop *without* using the parameter `-Append` (available in PowerShell v3 and newer). That overwrites your output file with each iteration, leaving you with just the data of the last server.

Either use the parameter `-Append` (if you have PowerShell v3 or newer):

```
foreach ($server in $servers) {
   ...
   New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $infoObject1 |
     Export-Csv -Append -Path .\Server_Inventory_$((Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy')).csv -NoTypeInformation
}
```

or move `Export-Csv` outside the loop (works with all PowerShell versions):

```
(foreach ($server in $servers) {
   ...
   New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $infoObject1
}) | Export-Csv -Path .\Server_Inventory_$((Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy')).csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Note that you need to run the loop in parentheses for this to work, as `foreach` loops don't output to the pipeline.

You could also replace the `foreach` loop with `ForEach-Object` if you want to feed the pipeline directly:

```
Get-Content .\Server.txt | ForEach-Object {
   $server = $_
   ...
   New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $infoObject1
} | Export-Csv -Path .\Server_Inventory_$((Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy')).csv -NoTypeInformation
```